# Python isalpha giving wrong results

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling, isalpha

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
       for line in f:
         line.isalpha()
 
False
```

File has only one line and contents are:
"abc"

Comment: check for newline and space characters at the end of the line. line.strip().isalpha() should return True

Comment: yeah, wow! It gives 'true'. Why strip()? Do we need to strip even if there's only 1 line in a file?

Comment: There is not only one line in your file. `strip()` will remove all whitespaces at beginning and end of the line, so also removing newlines. A file without a newline at the end will return `True`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because there is a space after the "abc" content

Comment: No there's none. I've checked it, no space(s).

Comment: @MuhammadIdreesHassan You're sure there are no newline(s) too ?

Comment: My bad, I didn't knew that newline is present at the end of each line. Using strip() has given correct results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know file lines are usually terminated by newline character `\n` which is the answer why `isalpha()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

As the others pointed out, it must be for some other characters in the file; likely either "\n" for line termination, or some others.

In brief, you want to remove those characters. Try:

```
line.strip().isalpha()
```

Full explanation below.

Load data:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
       for line in f:
         line.isalpha()
```

The output of line is:

```
>>> line
'abc\n'
```

And of course the result of `isalpha()` is false:

```
>>> print(line.isalpha())
False
```

However, removing the `\n` you obtain the correct result:

```
>>> line.strip()
'abc'
>>> line.strip.isalpha()
True
```

(To troubleshoot this, you may want to just output the line in the interpreter, without `print` statements, otherwise you won't see special characters as `'\n'`)